# Updating text in an html file and two JSON files (unix)

Tags: shell, unix, sed, scripting, command-line-interface

I want to come up with a way of updating three files at once. The three files are in the same directory. The input will be an id (key), an English translation, and a Spanish translation.

Let's say our three files look like this

index.html

`<div id="foo">goodbye</div>`

english.json

`{ "foo": "goodbye" }`

spanish.json

`{ "foo": "adios" }`

Let's say we want those three files to say 'hello' instead. We input 'foo' 'hello' 'hola' and this is how the files should look:

index.html

`<div id="foo">hello</div>`

english.json

`{ "foo": "hello" }`

spanish.json

`{ "foo": "hola" }`

Maybe sed is the right way to go? I've never used it but I am willing to learn how if this can be solved using it. Ideally this should be done from the command line somehow.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html  | Maybe sed is the right way to go? - What is "right" or "wrong" is king of opinion based question. It's possible do to with three sed commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i "s/\(.*<div id=\"$1\">\)[^<]*\(<.*\)/\1$2\2/g" index.html
sed -i "s/\(.*\"$1\":\).*/\1 \"$2\" }/g" english.json
sed -i "s/\(.*\"$1\":\).*/\1 \"$3\" }/g" spanish.json
```

USAGE: scriptname KEY ENGLISH SPANISH

Comment: Thank you! I am getting these errors when I run it, any ideas? I'm brand new to sed

`sed: 1: "public/index.html": extra characters at the end of p command`

`sed: 1: "english.json": invalid command code e`

`sed: 1: "spanish.json": unterminated substitute pattern`